# Do Vuex actions and mutations *really* support typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuex

Here’s a “typed” vuex action:

```
getItems({ dispatch }: ActionContext<State, RootState>, payload: string) {
  // ...
}
```

However, when I call it from a different action, or module, it doesn't check the payload type, or whether the specified action even exists:

```
myOtherAction({ dispatch }: ActionContext<State, RootState>) {
  dispatch('getItems', 1) // no error
  dispatch('getLemons') // no error
}
```

That is because mutations are called with `dispatch` method, and here's how vuex types it:

```
export interface Dispatch {
  (type: string, payload?: any, options?: DispatchOptions): Promise<any>;
  <P extends Payload>(payloadWithType: P, options?: DispatchOptions): Promise<any>;
}
```

So, as long as a dispatch follows this schema: `dispatch(string, any)`, it'll be allowed.

To me it defeats the whole purpose of typing the store in the first place. Has anyone encountered this problem and how've you dealt with it? Thanks

Comment: It doesn’t “support” it in the way we’d like to, as you’ve noticed. You can dispatch whatever you want and it’s not checked by the compiler. One could write a method to do this type-safely by inferring names etc from the store, but I’ll rather move on to Pinia or Vuex 5 (which may be Pinia practically) and don’t expect Vuex to implement any actual type checking in the current versions.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yep, considering pinia now...